# performing a sort of "reverse lookup" in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of spec numbers that require additional comments to be entered on a printed form when the form is generated. When I am generating that form, I have a list of products and their associated spec numbers. Some of the "normal" products are just plain old eight-digit numbers and I can easily search my comment table for a matching spec number and pull the appropriate comment. But there are also "special" products that have a suffix appended (for instance, 52498762 vs. 52498762-A4). Depending on the suffix used (there are two or three), *any* product with that suffix needs the comment listed. But when the comment table was set up, rather than specify each individual spec number with that suffix, the spec field has just the suffix. For example:

```
SpecID    |  Comment
------------------------------------------------------
52498762  |  Comment for a specific spec number
52746627  |  Comment for a different spec number
A4        |  Comment for any spec that ends with '-A4'
```

So in this example, if I had a spec number of 52196748-A4, it would need the comment listed in the 'A4' row of the comment table. I could have two hundred specs ending in -A4, and they would all get the same comment. Is there a way of writing a query that matches a wildcard version of the table contents? I know normally one matches a fixed value in a table against a wildcard user-supplied value; what I need is a static user-supplied value and a wildcard table value. Is that even possible?

Comment: Are all suffixes delimited by a `-`? In your application you should be able to separate the spec number and the suffix. The comment(s) can be retrieved using `SELECT Comment FROM Table WHERE SpecID = @SpecId OR SpecId = @Suffix`.

Comment: It sounds as if the Suffix takes precedence over the SpecID, so the query should be `SELECT Comment FROM Table WHERE SpecID = CASE WHEN @Suffix = '' THEN @SpecID ELSE @Suffix END`

Comment: Please describe a little more the format of your SpecIDs and Suffices. If they have some kind of consistent make-up that allows them to be reliably distinguished, this will be easy.

Comment: @Erik - what you see is what they are. They will always be at least 8 numbers, and in most cases that's all they'll be. If they're different, it'll be a two-character suffix set off by a `-`.

I think Chris' solution works - there could be cases where I might need both the generic suffix comment as well as a specific comment for that particular spec number, and splitting them in code and feeding both parts in via a stored proc should catch both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not get both sets of comments at once?

```
SELECT
   ...
FROM
   Products P
   LEFT JOIN Comments C
      ON P.ProductID LIKE C.SpecID + '%'
      OR P.ProductID LIKE '%-' + C.SpecID
```

Also you could consider:

```
SELECT
   ...
FROM
   Products P
   LEFT JOIN Comments C
      ON (Len(C.SpecID) = 2 AND P.ProductID LIKE C.SpecID + '%')
      OR (Len(C.SpecID) > 2 AND P.ProductID LIKE '%-' + C.SpecID)
```

Testing is in order to see if one performs better than the other. If you find the queries to be too slow, then trying adding some persisted calculated columns: in Products to specify whether the product ID has a dash in it or not, and in Comments add two columns, one with only product IDs and one with only suffices. Indexes on these columns could help.

```
ALTER TABLE Comments ADD ExactSpecID AS 
   (CASE WHEN Len(SpecID) > 2 THEN SpecID ELSE NULL END) PERSISTED
ALTER TABLE Comments ADD Suffix AS 
   (CASE WHEN Len(SpecID) = 2 THEN SpecID ELSE NULL END) PERSISTED
```

Comment: That's almost all I need. The first query does pull all the correct comments (I tested it by running it against the entire product table). I'd love to add it to my stored proc that pulls data from a few different tables into one product summary row, but the possibility exists that I could have two comments on a given product spec, at which point my proc would return two rows. I'll probably have to keep this as a separate proc and handle the possibility of multiple comments in my code. Anyway, though, this is what I need!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know your layout but...

```
SELECT
    p.ProductID,
    p.ProductName,
    c.CommentText
FROM
    Products p
    INNER JOIN Comments c
        ON 
           RIGHT(p.ProductID, LEN(p.ProductID) - CHARINDEX('-', p.ProductID))
           = 
           c.SpecID
```

So that should give you all the characters before the '-' in your ProductID string. And match that to the SpecID on the comments table? Is that what you were looking for?